# SSRS Use the text field only in a specific value the parameter

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2012

I have a report in ssrs 
When run the report, i use the parameter: STATUS and the value of the parameter: successfully, in process, lost.
The report contains a text field, the text field uses the expression to hide the element: =IIF(NOT IsNothing(Fields!filepath.Value), True, False)

If the text field becomes visible from the expression (=IIF(NOT IsNothing(Fields!filepath.Value), True, False))  I want to see the text field only when I select report parameter values "in process".
this can be done?

Answer (score 0):

Can you not use

```
=IIF(Parameters!STATUS.Value = "in process" True, False)
```

as your visibility expression?

Answer (score 0):

```
=(IsNothing(Fields!filepath.Value) = False) OR Parameters!STATUS.Value != "in process"
```

The above is not tested but I think it will work.

Basically is does not use IIF, it simply evaluates two expressions to true or false.
The code reads...
If the filepath is not empty OR if the status is not "in process" then return true (Hidden). If both the expressions are false then it will return False (show). It's a little counter-intuitive ...

Answer (score 0):

You should use an AND condition as you want the text to display only when both conditions are satisfied.Try this condition for the hidden expression in visibility for your text-

```
=IIF((IsNothing(Fields!filepath.Value) = False) AND (Parameters!STATUS.Value = 
 "in process"),false,true)
```